# Detecting every MouseEvent in JavaFx scene

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

I want to detect every `MouseEvent` in my JavaFx `Scene`, especially mouse clicks. My following solution works for some clicks, but only on some controls not for every control. So my question is, is there a way to detect every `MouseReleased` event on all `Nodes` of a `Scene`?

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, (EventHandler<MouseEvent>) event -> {
    EventTarget comp = event.getTarget();
    logger.debug("## " + (comp != null ? comp.getClass().getSimpleName() : event.getClass().getSimpleName()) + " [" + event.getEventType() + "] ## Komponente: " + event.getTarget() + " --------> Details:" + event);
});
```

Comment: Try `addEventFilter` instead of `addEventHandler`. You are probably missing events that get consumer before your handler catches them.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem! I suspected consumed event as cause of missing events but i haven't noticed the difference between addEventFilter and addEventHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @James_D suggestion, my logging is now working. To catch all events, its necessary to use an `EventFilter` because an `EventHandler` is missing `Event` that are already consumed. The doc explains the differences:

> **addEventFilter**
> Registers an event filter to this scene. The filter is called when the scene receives an Event of the specified type during the capturing phase of event delivery.
>
> **addEventHandler**
> Registers an event handler to this scene. The handler is called when the scene receives an Event of the specified type during the bubbling phase of event delivery.

A working code example:

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, (EventHandler<MouseEvent>) event -> {
    EventTarget comp = event.getTarget();
    logger.debug("## " + (comp != null ? comp.getClass().getSimpleName() : event.getClass().getSimpleName()) + " [" + event.getEventType() + "] ## Komponente: " + event.getTarget() + " --------> Details:" + event);
});
```